# How to check if a number can be represented as product of 2 consecutice numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

How to check if a number can be represented as product of 2 consecutice numbers?

Eg 56 can be represented since 56 = 7*8

72 can be represented since  72 = 8*9

Comment: Hint:  $\sqrt {56}=7.4833$ and $\sqrt {72}=8.4853$

Comment: $x(x+1)=n$ is a simple [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) so [it suffices that $\sqrt{4n+1}$ be an odd integer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int+dx%2F(1%2Bx^2)^2)

Comment: \sqrt {n}*\sqrt {n+1} ==  n?

Comment: What?  No... $\sqrt{n}\times \sqrt{n}=n\neq \sqrt{n}\times\sqrt{n+1}$ (*for positive real numbers*)

Comment: if  floor(sqrt(n)) * floor(sqrt(n+1)) = n , then it's true?

Comment: One could check that $n$ is not a perfect square and that $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor \times \lceil \sqrt{n}\rceil = n$.  If so, then yes and those numbers are $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ and $\lceil \sqrt{n}\rceil$ respectively.  Otherwise it can't.  In your most recent comment, you talked about $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ and $\lfloor \sqrt{n+1}\rfloor$, but these might be the same number.

Comment: Rather than just blindly guessing, why not try some numerical examples?

Comment: and if the numbers are not necessary to be consecutive then how to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the number you want to test is $N > 0$. Then, you are asking whether the following quadratic has a positive integer solution:
$$x(x + 1) = N.$$

Note that the solutions of the above can be explicitly found as:

$$x = \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{4N + 1}}{2}.$$

Now, it is clear that $4N + 1$ must be a perfect square. For otherwise, both the roots will be irrational. Now, the good thing to observe is that if $4N + 1$ is a perfect square, then its square root is odd. Thus, the number

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{4N + 1} - 1}{2}$$
is indeed an integer!

Thus, this concludes the discussion and gives you the necessary and sufficient condition:
$$\sqrt{4N+1} \text{ must be a perfect square.}$$

(Moreover, you also have the way of finding the two consecutive integers using the above formula.)

---

EDIT: For three numbers: We could proceed in the same manner.
Set up the cubic $x(x+1)(x+2) = N$ and use the [cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula) to test if any of the three roots is a positive integer. The criteria, in this case, might not be as simple.

This can be extended for 4 integers as well using the same method. However, for 5 or more, we would run into a problem as we don't have a closed-form expression for the roots of a polynomial of degree 5 (or higher). (Note that it doesn't mean that we can't solve *any* degree 5 polynomial. Maybe you still could exploit some symmetry and do it.)

Comment: And what if we had to check for 3 consecutive numbers?

Comment: @codelium: edited the answer to include a note on that.